# Pragma omp parallel sections

Tags: c++, openmp

Can I use pragma omp parallel sections to solve two concurrent parts of my code which are calling the same function by its address??

In this case, is it the case that the function being called has common variables for both the thread and hence the speedup is not happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I …?

Yes.

> In this case, is it the case that the function being called has common variables for both the thread and hence the speedup is not happening?

Hmm? Local variables in that function are *local to the thread*. Whether you call it via its address or directly is irrelevant. You get problems only if the function modifies global state.

Comment: In my case, the function is indeed modifying variables not local to the function. What do i do then?